# Qt4 + CGAL - Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"

Tags: c++, boost, qt4, cgal

I'm getting the error `Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"` while trying to compile a code with Qt4 and CGAL. I'm not using Boost directly and I've already searched and tried a bunch of options like `-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED`and `-DBOOST_NO_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION`. The versions I'm working with are CGAL 4.1.0, Qt 4.8.4_6 and Boost 1.53.0_1, and using CMake to generate the Makefile, in a machine Mac OS 10.8.2. Any ideas of what could be causing that error?

Answer (score 21):

This problem happens in Boost 1.56.0 with QT 4.7.4 (which is quite old now),

Regardless, another quick workaround is to edit the problematic boost header files,
and

```
add to the top:
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN

add to the bottom:
#endif
```

This will at least let MOC run without dying.

Comment: As an addition: The `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN .. #endif` statement has to encapsulate all boost-related includes in your code. It should not encapsulate Qt or STL-includes.

Answer (score 18):

When you compile a piece of code that defines Qt objects, the build system needs to call the [Qt Meta Object Compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html), aka "moc". In Qt versions before 5.0, the "moc" compiler (actually a precompiler) does not parse correctly all C++ code. In particular, it does not fully expand preprocessor macros. In recent Boost versions, some macros (like that BOOST_JOIN) are sometimes used to define a namespace name. For example:

```
namespace BOOST_JOIN(BOOST_TT_TRAIT_NAME,_impl) {
```

in `boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp` of Boost version 1.53.

[A Qt bug](http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829) has being filled at Qt-Project.org and is [said to be fixed in Qt-5.0](http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829?focusedCommentId=192942&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-192942).

In [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org)-4.2, I have tried to suppress those build errors by separating more the use of Qt and Boost in different compilation units. You should retry with a recent version of Boost, and CGAL-4.2-beta1 (or later versions if they are released when you read that answer). Let me know if you encounter similar problems with CGAL-4.2-beta1 or later.

As for Qt-5.0, I hope CGAL-4.3 will support it. We will have to work on the CMake scripts to support it. It will be added to the planning of the next CGAL developers meeting.

Comment: "In Qt versions before 5.0, the "moc" compiler (actually a precompiler) does parse correctly all C++ code" - you mean it does _not_ correctly parse all code, I think.

Comment: @davmac Thanks. +1 to your comment. I have modified the answer accordingly. It is strange that that typo was unnoticed until then.

Answer (score 6):

I downgraded to Boost 1.52, and now it's compiling.